# Set Firefox as default browser

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

I have moved between various browsers and used Chrome for the last couple of weeks, but the fact that is crashing multiple times per day has driven me back to Firefox.

Where can I set Firefox as my default browser? I can't find it.

Thanks.

Edit: XPPro SP3

Comment: You fail to mention your operating system. How to set your default browser completely depends on that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your version this might change slightly...

Menu Tools, Options, Advanced, tab General, group "System Defaults", checkbox "Always check to see if Firefox is the default browser on startup".

Comment: 2 helpful comments. Both upvoted, clearer one selected.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Tools menu and then select Options.

Select the Advanced panel then click the General tab, and then click Check Now button.  Then respond Yes to make it default.